# Use CHOOSE with an IF statement to return a season

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm using Excel to create a formula that will calculate which season had more deliveries by drivers. I'm doing an assignment and this is the original question:

> Show if the Drivers were making more deliveries during the summer or during the Christmas time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(C2:N2,index(MAXIFS(
```

Here is a image of my spreadsheet:

[image: my excel spreadsheet]

As you can see the month are on the top and I want Excel to choose the season based on the month with the highest deliveries made by drivers to show.

Comment: Due to the uneven abbreviation, the months in row 2 seem to be text, not true dates formatted as *mmm* or *mmmm*. They need to be true dates to use MONTH in that formula.

Comment: Ultimately it is profit that matters. Whether fuel charges in summer or Christmas time are significantly different, if not then what is the fuel consumption per kilometer by a driver should be taken into account.

Comment: Could you please give a formula for this I’m really stuck

Comment: Wouldn't you just need `COUNTIFS()` or `SUMIFS()`? And just count the deliveries in each range?

Comment: No formula could even be guessed at as there are no strict definitions for either 'summer' or 'Christmas time' for which to gauge against the months listed in row 2.

Comment: I mean for the summer and winter period

Comment: That still tells me nothing. What months **specifically** are 'summer'?  What months **specifically** are 'winter'?

Comment: During may june July August for summer and for winter November December

Answer (score 0):

Because you definition of summer is and winter is kind of subjective, you need to add all the columns that match the month in question together in a hard coded way.  Perhaps with a list off to the side or a start and end month for each period with the dates as excel dates you could do things a little different.

The formula below sums the totals for the specified months and compares them to each other.  If summer total is high, it states it in text if its true.  If that fails, it test to see if the winter months are higher and states it in text if its true.  If this is false, this means that winter is not greater than summer and that summer is not greater than winter.  The only remaining choice is that they are equal and this is returned in text.

```
=IF(SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"May")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"June")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"July")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Aug")>SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Nov")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Dec"),"SUMMER HAS GREATER DELIVERIES",IF(SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"May")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"June")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"July")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Aug")<SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Nov")+SUMIFS(D12:O12,$D$2:$O$2,"Dec"),"WINTER HAS GREATER DELIVERIES","SUMMER AND WINTER HAVE THE SAME DELIVERIES"))
```

Comment: I as thinking that AVERAGE should be used to compare 4 months to 2 months.

Comment: than state that in your question.  In your question the way it was worded at the time was which period had MORE deliveries not which period had a higher AVERAGE delivery.  simple adjust though, just divide each side the of the comparison operater by the number of months on its side.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the op. Just another userXXXXX. I stll don't think there is sufficient information to offer a perfect answer but I gave my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using CHOOSE is a bit convoluted but it can be made to work. I've also used true dates in row 2.

> During may june July August for summer and for winter November December

Since you are comparing 4 months to 2 months, you will need AVERAGE rather than SUM or individual month totals.

```
=CHOOSE(IF(AVERAGE(G13:J13)>AVERAGE(M13:N13), 1, IF(AVERAGE(G13:J13)<AVERAGE(M13:N13), 2, 3)), "summer", "winter", "summer & winter tied")
```